# How to save data using JQuery in ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to Jquery and MVC. I am try to insert some student records. I tried a jquery code for this but it is not working. It didn't display a view also when i set the post method URL in jquery function. I am not able to get what is the error and where i am going wrong. Here is my code of jquery which i am using.

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.growl.js"></script>
 <link href="~/StyleSheets/jquery.growl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script>
        function Submit() {
              if (!IsValied()) {
                    return;
              }
              $.growl.notice({ message: "Please Wait.." });
              var sex = 1;
              if (document.getElementById("male").checked == true) {
                  sex = 1;
              } else {
                  sex = 2;
              }
              var params = {
                   StudentId: $('#txtStudentId').val(),
                   StudentName: $('#txtStudentName').val(),
                   Age: $('#txtAge').val(),
                   Gender: sex
              };
              $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                   url: '/Student/Create',
                   data: params,
                   success: function (data) {
                       $.growl.notice({ message: "Successfully Saved" });
                   },
                   error: function (req, status, error) { 
                       $.growl.error({ message: "Error" });
                   }
              });
         }

         function IsValied() {
              if (jQuery('#txtStudentId').val() == "") {
                   $.growl.warning({ message: "Enter Student Id" });
                   return false;
              }
              else if (jQuery('#txtStudentName').val() == "") {
                   $.growl.warning({ message: "Enter Student Name" });
                   return false;
               } else if (jQuery('#txtAge').val() < 0) {
                   $.growl.warning({ message: "Enter Age" });
                   return false;
               }
               return true;
         }
 </script>

 <!-- end snippet -->
```

I created POST method as follows.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Student student)
{
      SchoolContext studentObj = new SchoolContext();
      using (SchoolContext OdContext = new SchoolContext())
      {
          Student objStudent = new Student();
          objStudent.StudentId = student.StudentId;
          objStudent.StudentName = student.StudentName;
          objStudent.Age = student.Age;
          objStudent.Gender = (byte)student.Gender;
          OdContext.Students.Add(objStudent);
          OdContext.SaveChanges();
          return Json(student, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      }

 }
```

Please tell me how can I do it?

Comment: Thanks i did it. the thing is when i run this, the view is not loading.. any idea? i am very new to mvc. when i use the url as '/Student/Create' in the function , the Create view is not loaded.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Can you be more specific on what you mean by _View is not loading_? Does data gets saved at first instance?

Comment: you need to declare jquery before the declaration of the plugin

Comment: this is the error. but i used the same URL as previous . The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Student/Create

Comment: there should be two action method with name `public ActionResult Create` one with `[HttpPost]` second without `[HttpPost]` do you have two method in controller?

Comment: Your one action method should be like this 
`public ActionResult Create()
{ return View()}` and one more should be like the `HttpPost` you have written

Comment: thanks.. i put another create method. Thanks a lot.. it works